# Vbs script working fine with CMD but not in Code

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, vbscript

When I execute the script via code it's going in an infinite loop. But same script working in CMD

tried with CMD and It's working but not working in code. Take any VB Script as a sample and validate.

```
    private string excecuteScript(string retValue)
    {
        try
        {
            string filetoexecute = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, Path.GetExtension(ScriptName).EndsWith(".vbs",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? "AA_MyVB.vbs" : "AA_MyJS.js");
            filetoexecute = string.Format("\"" + filetoexecute + "\"");

            string arguments = " " + filetoexecute + " " + ScriptInputPara + " \"" + ScriptName + "\" ";

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "WScript.exe"),
                Arguments = arguments,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true
            };

            var myProcess = CommonMethods.InvokeProcess(startInfo);

            StreamReader errorStream = myProcess.StandardError;
            StreamReader outputStream = myProcess.StandardOutput;
            string theOutput = string.Empty;

            bool stopWhile = false;
            while (!stopWhile)
            {
                stopWhile = myProcess.HasExited;
                if (CmdTask.IsTaskTimedout)
                {
                    stopWhile = true;
                    myProcess.Kill();
                }
            }
            theOutput += outputStream.ReadLine();

            TheError += errorStream.ReadToEnd();

            if (myProcess.ExitCode != 0)
            {
                TheError = "Error occurred while executing script file";
            }

            if (IsScriptTask && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(theOutput) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ScriptOutputPara))
                CmdTask.SetVariableValue(ScriptOutputPara, theOutput);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retValue = (ex.Message);
        }

        return retValue;
    }
```

Actual: `myProcess.HasExited` returns `false`

Expected: `myProcess.HasExited` returns `true`

if I execute `theOutput += outputStream.ReadLine();` before while loop then `myProcess.HasExited` returns true...

Comment: Can you share a little information about how you are executing this code please? This question is tagged with "vbscript" but there is not vbs in the question...

Comment: and it's tagged with dwscript but there's no DWScript...